# Is xlink:href deprecated for svg <image>s?

Tags: javascript, svg

According to [MDN xlink:href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href), we should use `href` instead of `xlink:href`, but on the [svg  example page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) (which was last updated July 6, 2017), the attribute in the example is `xlink:href`.

Does it matter which attribute is used?

Comment: I can't see a difference between `xlink:href` and `xlink:href`.

Comment: I'm not sure Safari supports href yet so yes I suppose it does matter currently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The upcoming SVG 2 standard is dropping the requirement for the `xlink:` prefix. Some browsers support that option, but not all do.  The safe (and backward compatible) option for now is to keep using it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `xlink:href` will be dropped but for now I think the best long term option is to use both attributes together.